# Performance of getting list of common elements in 2 array

Tags: swift

I have two arrays of custom objects, which has id and sum.
Like this:

```
let oldStakes = [Stake(id: 1, sum: 100), Stake(id: 2, sum: 120)]
let newStakes = [Stake(id: 5, sum: 600), Stake(id: 1, sum: 432)]
```

I need to get two arrays of objects with the same id.
If I'll do like this:

```
    newStakes = newStakes.filter{stake in oldStakes.contains{$0.id == stake.id}}.sorted{$0.id ?? 0 < $1.id ?? 0}
    oldStakes = oldStakes.filter{stake in oldStakes.contains{$0.id == stake.id}}.sorted{$0.id ?? 0 < $1.id ?? 0}
```

the execution time of this code is about 2 seconds.
How can I reduce execution time? Thanks!

Comment: `id` of `Stake` is Optional??!! Why?

Comment: If your Stake is `Hashable` you can do `Set(oldStakes).intersection(Set(newStakes))` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, searching in `Set` is O(1) operation and is faster in most cases.

```
var oldStakes = [Stake(id: 1, sum: 100), Stake(id: 2, sum: 120)]
var newStakes = [Stake(id: 5, sum: 600), Stake(id: 1, sum: 432)]
let oldIds = Set(oldStakes.lazy.map{$0.id ?? 0})
let newIds = Set(newStakes.lazy.map{$0.id ?? 0})
newStakes = newStakes.filter{oldIds.contains($0.id ?? 0)}.sorted{$0.id ?? 0 < $1.id ?? 0}
oldStakes = oldStakes.filter{newIds.contains($0.id ?? 0)}.sorted{$0.id ?? 0 < $1.id ?? 0}
```

But I wonder if you really need to make `id` Optional in your `Stake`.

Comment: Id is optional, because Stake is inited with json from server, and i think it's good to have optional in this case.

About a performance: 
With mine code : 1.7 sec
With your: 0.015 sec. 

Maybe is there any other solutions to improve? I wonder if it can be less than 0.001 :-)

Comment: @user3020463 Your argument about why `id` is optional is flawed. You don't have a valid `Stake` if there is no `id`. Don't make it optional, just skip that "stake".

Comment: @user3020463, I wonder _is inited with json from server_ can be a reason of making it Optional, but that's another issue. (Though using non-Optional can be a way to improve.) If you have a target time, you should better clarify other parameters like number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the `contains(_:)` function for arrays is slow. (It has `O(n)` performance for each check.) Sets have approximately `O(1)` performance for `contains(_:)`.

If you loop through an array and do a `contains()` check on every element, the result is `O(n²)` performance, which is really bad.

OOPer showed you how to refactor your code using `Set` objects to test for membership. You might also want to figure out way to not sort the results each time.

Comment: I need sort, because then I do something like that:
               ` for index in 0..<newStakes.count {
                    let newStake = newStakes[index]
                    let oldStake = oldStakes[index]
                   ...
               } `
And I have to be sure, that newStake and oldStake will be with the same id.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that filtered() preserves the order from the original array. Thus if you sort your array into the desired order once and leave it that way you won't have to sort it each time. The docs for Sequence.filter say: "Returns an array containing, in order..." and a quick test confirms that the order is preserved.

Comment: Yes, I know that filtered returns array with the same order, but the new array, which inited from server json can be in another order, which previous one. So that's why I have to sort it. And this array actually stored in another object. So it was just an example. 
Btw thank you for your answer!